# nodemon doesnt start the server file after restarting due to changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

It is said that pictures speak louder than words so...

As you can see nodemon works just fine by itself as expected:
[image: only nodemon]

then when i get express to the project nodemon just keeps restarting due to changes
[image: nodemon and express]

tried pretty much every solution i can find on the internet(including here on stack) for this problem nothing worked...
Can someone please tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've met the same error in the past and you can try these following ways:

**Solution 1:** Uninstall your nodemon and install it again by executing

```
npm uninstall -g nodemon
```

then

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

**Solution 2:** Your computer maybe lack of environment. Add this

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem;
```

into %PATH% environment variable which located in

```
Control Panel\System and Security\System
```

then move to

```
-> Advanced Settings System -> Environment Variables...
```

and reset your computer.

I hope these solutions work.